# How a WPF user control dll can share instance of resource

Tags: wpf, dll, user-controls, resources

I have multiple user controls in my dll. Since dll can not have app.xml so i can not have a single place to keep resource and use it everywhere the way it is possible in .exe. The only way I see is using merged dictionaries. By doing this it duplicates the resource instance to each user control. This is what i do not want. I need a single resource to get shared across all controls to keep performance impacts low. x:Shared = true does help to share the resource either.
Am i missing something or any other way ?

Comment: `Generic.xaml` is used for this purpose for `CustomControl`s. `App.xaml` is used for this for `UserControl`s in a WPF Application.

Comment: Sheridan, Thanks for responding. But the issue is as long as assembly is of "exe" App.xaml works great for user controls. But when we have user controls in dll then App.xaml can not be used.

Comment: Then don't put them into a class library... put them where they're supposed to be.

Comment: Please go through my question. I have to share resource instance within dll. I would like to understand it is possible in exe why not in dll? or is there any way to do it in dll.